# How do I make a jspdf autotable landscape?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

The table plugin JsPDF-AutoTable: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable how do I make the page landscape as oppose to portrait? In the documentation it just says "Only pt supported (not mm or in)". I don't understand how to make the page landscape; landscape makes sense for a lot of tables....

Answer (score 13):

Ok the answer is: var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');

It would be helpful if this was in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I have done it initializing jsPDF instance like this:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');
```

Here, **l** means **Landscape** format. For **portrait**, **p** can be used.